# Can I use Regex to read a user email address on input and then show/hide a div element if it matches @hotmail.com?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

I am looking to add a regex control which will read the customer email address as they type it (or have finished typing and the focus is no longer on that email textbox).

If the email address ends in "@hotmail.com" for example then a div element will be shown with more options (I think I have coded this part)

My code snippets are as follows:

jQuery

```
$().ready(function () {
  var Toggler = document.getElementById('chkYes');
  if (Toggler != null) {
    ToggleHOTMAIL(Toggler);
  }
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

Comment: In which field you want to check hotmail mail format?

Comment: In the Username Textbox field

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$(".email").on("keyup change", function() {
  if ($(this).val().match(/@hotmail\.com$/)){
    $(".myDiv").show();
  } else {
    $(".myDiv").hide();
  }
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7wwh2evk/)

Answer (score 0):

Generally you don't need RegExp for this task, but you can do this in such way:

```
$('#UserName').change(function() {
    var reExp = /.*@hotmail\.com$/;
    if (reExp.test($('#UserName').text())
    {
        // do sth
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('email-element').blur(function () {
    if($(this).val().search(/@hotmail\.com$/) != -1) {
    // show div..
    }
 });`

Basically your regex is `/@hotmail\.com$/`
It checks for `@hotmail` then escapes the `.` with `\` and then checks for `com`. And all that has to be the end of the string for which `$` stands at the end of your regex. The `search` function returns`-1` if no match is found. and if that's false `!= -1` you run your code for showing the div

Answer (score 0):

Your code shoud be like this.
In the `<div>` you just need to add one Id. Also first you need to hide it.

```
<div class="form-inline form-center" data-divname="PaymentMethod" id="divPaymentMethod"
            style="display: none">
```

**JQ code.**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("document").ready(function () {
            $("[id$=UserName]").blur(function () {
                if ($("[id$=UserName]").val() != "") {
                    var Name = $("[id$=UserName]").val();
                    if (Name.indexOf("@hotmail.com") > -1)
                    { $("[id$=divPaymentMethod]").show(); }
                    else { $("[id$=divPaymentMethod]").hide(); }
                }

            });
        });
</script>
```